# Excel Dynamic Drop Down Lists based on a Matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I am looking to control the options available in a series of drop down list (created using data validation) based on a control matrix.

In the example screenshot below, the first drop down list allows for the selection of either feature1 or feature2. If feature1 is selected then the X's in the matrix indicate that features4 and 5 are not allowed in drop down list 2 and drop down list 2 should only display features3 and 6 as possible selections. If feature 3 is then selected in the 2nd drop down list then drop down list 3 would only display feature8 as an option. Feature 7 is not available if feature 3 is selected and feature 9 was excluded by virtue of selecting feature1 at the start.

I hope that makes some sense. I would be interest in peoples ideas on the best approach / options available to achieve this level of control. I have use named ranges and the indirect function to achieve similar results but not when using a matrix to specify the available options. I would like to avoid blanks in the drop down lists.

[control matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puVJz.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot below shows how to do this using a dynamic list of values for your dropdowns.

The first list of values, `List Values 1`, is defined with formulas using the choices from the first two dropdown lists.  This list implements the logic shown in your matrix. If I have not translated your text properly into formulas, please adjust them as necessary.

[image]

The second list of values, `List Values 2`, creates a dynamic, ordered list of the values from `List Values 1`, placing any blank values at the end. The formulas in `E14` and `E18` are:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$5:E$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(E$5:E$8)-ROW(E$4))/(E$5:E$8<>""),ROWS($E$14:$E14)),1),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$9:E$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(E$9:E$11)-ROW(E$8))/(E$9:E$11<>""),ROWS($E$18:$E18)),1),"")
```

Finally, two formulas create arrays of the non-blank values in `List Values 2`, and are assigned to the names `List_2` and `List_3`, which are used to specify the list values for Dropdowns 2 and 3.  These formulas are shown in the screenshot.

I hope this helps, and good luck.
**______________________________________________________________________________**

**How it works:** The inner `AGGREGATE()` function above is doing the same thing that `SMALL()` would do (function=15), except it has an option to ignore errors (option=6) and it can perform array calculations without requiring <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The array it's operating on is `(ROW(E$5:E$8)-ROW(E$4))/(E$5:E$8<>"")`, which is the array `{1;2;3;4}` divided by the array of `True/False` values where the range `E5:E8` is not blank: `{False;True;True;False}`.

In arithmetic operations involving logical values, `True` and `False` are converted to 1's and 0's.  So the division gives the array `{#DIV/0!;2;3;#DIV/0!}`, and `AGGREGATE()` ignores the errors, giving the row numbers that aren't blank: `{2;3}`, in the case shown above.

This array is then used as the row_nums in an `INDEX()`, which returns the non-blank rows from `E5:E8`. Finally, `IFERROR()` returns a blank when `INDEX()` returns `#NUM!` as it is filled down further than the number of values in it's list of row_nums.

The formulas for the named ranges use `INDEX()` to return the last non-blank value in each list.  `SUM()` counts the number of non-blank cells in the range, and that is used as the row_num for `INDEX()`.

Comment: This deserves 10. :-)